# HtmlAgilityPack - strange ArgumentOutOfRange exception

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, tumblr

I need to parse Tumblr by getting some search results.
My code:

```
string tumblename = string.Empty;
string tumblepostid = string.Empty;
string tumbleposttext = string.Empty;
string EncodedCharRegex = "&#[X]?[0-9|A-F]{1,12};";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.tumblr.com/search/cheese");
   HtmlNodeCollection searchResults = doc.GetElementbyId("search_posts").SelectNodes("//article"); //<-- here
   foreach (HtmlNode result in searchResults)
   {
      tumblename = result.GetAttributeValue("data-tumblelog-name", "NULL");
      tumblepostid = result.GetAttributeValue("data-id", "NULL");
      tumbleposttext = result.ChildNodes[0].InnerText.Trim().Replace("&rsquo;", "'").Replace("&nbsp;", " ").Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace(".", ". ").Replace("&hellip;", "...").Replace("&mdash;", "-");
      var z = Regex.Matches(tumbleposttext, EncodedCharRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
      foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(tumbleposttext, EncodedCharRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant))
      tumbleposttext = tumbleposttext.Replace(m.Value, WebUtility.HtmlDecode(m.Value));
      listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { tumblename, tumblepostid, tumbleposttext }));
    }
}
```

All was well, and the code ran perfectly. BUT -- when I created a new WinForms project and copy-pasted that code into the new WinForms project without any changes, the program now crashes in the mentioned place.

The old (original) project is still working correctly.

What could it be?

Comment: You have included the error message but I do not see where you have indicated which line of code is getting the error.

Comment: @DavidTansey it breaks on the 8th line, I wrote a comment at its end.